# TypeError: 'range' object does not support item assignment

Tags: python, python-3.x

Дан одномерный массив числовых значений, насчитывающий N элементов. Исключить из него М элементов, начиная с номера К.

```
N = 10
K = 5
M = 2
mas = range(N)
print (mas)
mas [K:K+M] = []
print (mas)
```

Ошибка:
mas [K:K+M] = []
TypeError: 'range' object does not support item assignment

Comment: @Antonru лучше поменяйте заголовок. Заголовки типа "срочно нужна помощь", "люди помогите" и тд обычно имеют обратный эффект

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
mas=list(range(N)) #!!!!!
del(mas[K:K+M])
```

или

```
mas [K:K+M]=[]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print (list(mas[:K]) + list(mas[K+M:]))
```

Comment: Всё ровно ошибка. На mas ругается. Если объявить в скобки. То опять ошибка

Comment: @Antonru, у меня работает, пишите, какая конкретно ошибка (небось на принт в скобках ругается).

Comment: видимо у вопрошающего 3 питон, а у Fike - второй.

Comment: Да, у меня третий питон. Простите что сразу не сказал

Comment: @Antonru, взял на себя смелость отредактировать ответ @LinnTroll, попробуйте.

Comment: Спасибо, всё работает теперь.

Comment: Ну или так:
> N = 10
> K = 5
> M = 2
> mas = list(range(10))
> print (mas)
> mas [K:K+M] = []
> print (mas)